# 3D WPF charts with custom objects

Tags: wpf, 3d, charts, user-interaction

I am new to 3D and charting in WPF.

What I would like to do is building a chart with my own 3D objects inside it. I don't want to display classical points or bubbles, but my own 3D objects (cubes for example). And I want that the user can interact with each object on the chart (rotate a cube using mouse for example).

I wonder if there are libraries to do this kind of things or if I have to do it by myself using WPF 3D or something else.